# Converting Eclipse plugin to Intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, intellij-idea

I have an eclipse plugin which I want convert to an intellij plugin. Is there a quick way to do that. What will be the design patterns I can use?

Comment: Design patterns?  Follow their respective APIs for plugins.

Comment: Which plugin is it? You probably can only copy-paste the "model" of the plugin, i.e. the part that does the manipulation of some data or what it does. There is no trivial way to port the graphical part of the plugin, since Eclipse and IntelliJ have different API's for doing that.

Comment: @Jes - This is my plugin at http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/. I was asking about the model, e.g. `Resource`, `Folder`, etc which are eclipse specific. So I need to have my model object and map it to eclipse or intellij. Which design pattern is suitable for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there is no simple and quick way to do this. You need to deeply undestand plugin structure and plugin API of Eclipse and IDEA

Comment: Thanks, is there any docs which should help convert one to another?

Answer (score 4):

1. first you need fully understand the plugin your are porting.
2. setup intellij plugin development environment.      http://www.jetbrains.org/display/IJOS/Writing+Plug-ins
3. understand intellij architecture:
   http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+Architectural+Overview
4. read Getting started with plugin development:
   http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Getting+Started+with+Plugin+Development
   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AktCFxC9Bx0
5. the sourcecode of intelliJ is very helpful when your need documentation of some functions or classes.
6. a plugin sourcecode: https://github.com/whunmr/emacsIDEAs